# Power series $\sin$

Tags: power-series

Suppose $f$ is holomorphic and $|f(\sin z)|<\infty.$  Then can I say $f(\sin z)=\sum_n^\infty a_n(\sin z)^n$ for $a_n\in\mathbb{C}$? Where does $|f(\sin z)|<\infty$ assumption play role here?

Edit: Domain of $f$ is not entire $\mathbb{C}$ plane.

Comment: By your data, if you meant $\;f(\sin z)\;$ is bounded for all $\;z\in\Bbb C\;$ , then it is holomorphic and bounded  and thus by Liouville's Theorem it is a constant map...

Comment: @DonAntonio I am considering case when the domain is not the entire $\mathbb{C}$ plane. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Fine, then $\;f(\sin z)\;$ is analytic as $\;\sin z\;$ is analytic at every single complex point, and thus a Taylor series exists for that function.

Comment: @DonAntonio So we don't need to assume the boundedness?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, it is bounded on any compact subset of its domain.

Comment: @ToInfinity Not at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is analytic in a neighbourhood of $0$, it has a Maclaurin series: there is $r > 0$ such that
$$ f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n \ \text{for}\ |z| < r $$

That implies
$$ f(\sin(x)) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \sin(x)^n \ \text{whenever}\ |\sin(x)| < r $$

Since $\sin$ is continuous, there is some $\epsilon$ such that this is true when $|x| < \epsilon$.

The condition $|f(\sin(x))| < \infty$ plays no role.  Indeed, without specifying for what $x$ this is true, it is essentially meaningless.